# Charles works as proxy but doesn't record http requests

Tags: proxy, firefox

I have installed latest version of Charles Web Proxy and use default proxy settings (port 8888)
I have configured Mozilla Firefox to use this port locally for proxy
My browser works through proxy as expected (when I shutdown Charles - Mozilla becomes blind and doesn't open any site). But for some reason - Charles doesn't record a single HTTP request, though Record was started.

What should I check? [image]

Thank in you advance! [image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was because I had a VPN opened. Once I closed the VPN, CharlesProxy started to record my requests.